# Uncaught TypeError: Why can't it read ID when everything is working?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-7, react-error-boundary

Using Rails backend and React frontend, a user can comment on a post and can like/unlike a post. Everything works as intended but when I am on the PostDetail.js, and I refresh the page, I get an error message.

```
PostDetail.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at PostDetail (PostDetail.js:27:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

The above error occurred in the  component:
at PostDetail (http://localhost:4000/main.392f23b132859f3bd7ac.hot-update.js:41:56)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:41906:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:42538:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:42476:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:40582:5)
at App
at ContentProvider (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:1145:3)
at UserProvider (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:1335:3)
at ErrorProvider (http://localhost:4000/static/js/bundle.js:1256:3)
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error-handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Here are my codes:

```
function PostDetail () {
const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
const { contents, deletePost } = useContext(ContentContext);
const postId = parseInt(useParams().id);
const post = contents.find(post => post.id === postId);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [commentMode, setCommentMode] = useState(false);
const openComment = () => setCommentMode(commentMode => !commentMode);
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        setLiked(data.liked);
    })
    .catch(error => setErrors(error))
}, [post.id, setErrors])
```

It is saying that it cannot read the property of the id in }, [post.id, setErrors])

Comment: `const post = contents.find(post => post.id === postId);` try using another name to post in the find method.

Comment: like `const post = contents.find((p) => p.id === postId);`

Comment: @AhmerSaud, I just tried that and it still throws me an error message =(

Comment: Hey @janestack, you should console.log() your postId first , if its valid then check that your list if it actually has that element with the id , otherwise array.find() will return a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, which will cause the error.

Comment: @AhmerSaud, I just console.log(postId) and it is giving me the correct post_id. I've been messing around with it for hours and looks like more of my codes are breaking =(

Comment: ok try changing your useEffect dependecies to [postId,setErrors] instead of post.id, 
looks like post.id is not a valid dependecy array

Comment: and use postId in your fetch api

Comment: @AhmerSaud, Once I changed the post.id to postId another error message pops up. It's now saying that the title in post.title is undefined.

Comment: well looks like something is wrong with data.

Comment: There is no post with that I'd in contents array hence `post` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
        setLiked(data.liked);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        setErrors(error)
    })
}, [post.id, setErrors])
```

Maybe you missing a '{}' in the catch(error.. ?
Cause I see it return setErrors?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jin! I just gave that a try and still getting the same error messages =(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).